# I'd like to be able to view a single day on my reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Currently when you view your user profile and select your reputation history, you get a lovely little chart detailing the growth of your reputation score, and you can select a range of dates to see a list of exactly what questions garnered you how much reputation during that period.  However, the range MUST start on a different date than it ends upon.

Being the sort of geek who loves to watch numbers go up, I would like the default graph to have the ability to display one single day's worth of reputation so I can see, for example, how close I am (or was) to hitting the rep cap that day, and which questions/answers did best on just that day.

If this does get implemented, a nice shortcut might be to have the dots on the chart be double-clickable to display that one day.

Comment: I suppose this can be tagged as [status-completed] now. The graph is gone, but [your reputation tab](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2490/hellion?tab=reputation) now has a nice breakdown of your recent points.

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort of* do this:

1. Visit https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation
2. Scroll down to the bottom.

The format is:
`1 234567 (10)`, where 1 is the vote type, 234567 is the post ID, and 10 is the reputation earned or lost, excluding square bracketed reputation (`[10]`). The votes are listed in the order they were cast.

Comment: I know, and I've been using that feature a fair bit, but seeing [2 12882 10  / 2 12882 10 / 3 12883 15] isn't nearly as nice as "+20: Mine vs. Mein, +15: Sesquipedalian logorrhea".